# What is the magnitude and direction of the change in velocity if the inital velocity is 30m/s south and the final velocity is 40m/s west?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

I got the magnitude correct which is 50 m/s however I don't know how to solve for the direction of change. Any help?

Comment: Use vectors to find both magnitude and direction.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a difference vector $\Delta \vec{v}$ is given by
$$\Delta \vec{v} = \vec{v}_f - \vec{v}_i$$
where $\vec{v}_f$ and $\vec{v}_i$ are the final and initial vector respectively.

Your calculation for the magnitude of $\Delta \vec{v}$ is correct.
For the direction, draw a vector diagram and notice that $\Delta \vec{v}$ points somewhere north-west.

[image]

The exact angle it makes with the $-x$-axis is the angle between $\vec{v}_f$ and $\Delta\vec{v}$, given by
$$ \arctan \left( \frac{30}{40} \right) \approx 36.9^\circ. $$
This is equivalent to an angle of $180^\circ - 36.9^\circ = 143.1^\circ$ from the $+x$-axis.